# ParamValidationError when mocking AWS SQS client calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-sqs, botocore

When trying to mock sqs client and adding response for the method "send_message", I am facing ParamValidationError `botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:`

Using pytest and botocore.stub (following this [blob](https://blog.milancermak.com/2019/02/14/unit-testing-aws-services-in-python/) as well)
Here is the expected_response:

```
expected_params = {
            "QueueUrl": "abc",
            "MessageBody": "string",
            "MessageAttributes": {
                "CallbackClass": {"DataType": "String", "StringValue": None},
                "CallbackMethod": {"DataType": "String", "StringValue": None},
                "Key": {"DataType": "String", "StringValue": '{"package_name": "package_name", "min_version": 0, "max_version": 0}'},
            },
```

After changing the StringValues to `None`, StubAssertionError is resolved. Not sure how to avoid this in the validation. I tried stub.ANY but still same error.
`Invalid type for parameter MessageAttributes.CallbackClass.StringValue, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`
Any workaround for this?

This is how I am mocking the sqs client and sqs response (following the documentation for response structure):

```
    client = boto3.client("sqs", region_name="us-east-1", aws_access_key_id="...", aws_secret_access_key="...")
    mock_res = {
        "MD5OfMessageBody": "string",
        "MD5OfMessageAttributes": "string",
        "MD5OfMessageSystemAttributes": "string",
        "MessageId": "string",
        "SequenceNumber": "string",
    }
```

Comment: Are you still getting `Parameter validation failed:` error or is now that fixed and getting another error? Could you maybe modify the question step by step to reproduce this?

Comment: Same error `Parameter Validation failed`. The response I am getting contains `None` as StringValue for both CallbackClass and CallbackMethod and if I make it string, then It throws `StubAssertionError`. To match the service response, `None` doesn't passes the type validation.